# Email template subjects in foreign language become question marks when saved

Tags: email-templates, magento2.2.6, character-encoding

I have created and email template with Russian content. After entering the details and saved the email template, email template subject showing like "`???? ????????????? ?????? {{var store.getFrontendName() | raw}}` ". The issue is only with the email template subject field.
Magento version : 2.2.6

**Steps to reproduce :**

1. Go to Marketing -> Email Templates
2. Edit any template
3. Put the below characters in the subject line.

> Ваше подтверждение заказа {{var store.getFrontendName() | raw}}

4. Save

Comment: just checked in magento 2.2.3, its working there

Comment: I have checked it on m2.2.6 as well, and its working  there too. can you check in table `email_template` how data is being stored ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat i have checked "email_template" table content.In database the text is correctly saving. So the issue comes when the value is displaying. While searching in google i found that the issue comes from "dotmailer" module. They are decoding the email subject field value before displaying in backend. We are not using this module, so we have disabled the module. Issue fixed.

Comment: oh ok. please write your fix as answer so some other one can get help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to a new module found in Magento2.2 version ie "Dontmailer". In that module they are doing some UTF8 decoding with email template subject value, which was the issue. We have no use with that module in the current situation, so we have disabled the module. May be in later Magento version they will fix the bug.